# How to remove time from my date time column in python

Tags: python, python-datetime, custom-data-type

I am a beginner in python and need some guidance.
I read in several worksheets from a single Excel Workbook and appended them into a single dataframe in Python. However, the output file has changed my date column which is still defined as an object into a different date format and added time, see example below:

| Original date format | Date format outputed from Python |
| --- | --- |
| 02/03/1992 | 1992-02-03 00:00:00 |

This is the code I used to append the worksheets

```
*import pandas as pd

# First, combine all the pages in each Workbook into one sheet

df_toAppend = pd.concat(pd.read_excel('C:/Sam/Predicting Outcomes .xlsx', sheet_name=None), ignore_index=True)*
```

I have tried to just extract the date from the column, but it says its needs to be a date stamp

I have tried the following to extract just the date part:

```
df['Date_of_Birth']=df['Date_of_Birth'].dt.date
```

but get the following error: *AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values*

I have also tried the following:

```
df['Date_of_Birth'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date_of_Birth'], format ='%Y%M%d')
```

But the error message below is returned:
*ValueError: time data '(Timestamp('1982-06-10 00:00:00'), '%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S.%f')' does not match format '%Y%M%d' (match)*

I have also tried the following to split the time from the date and then try, but the error message says: *AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!*

```
pd.to_datetime(df['Date_of_Birth'].str.split(':', n=1).str[0])
```

Python is saying my Date_of_Birth column is an object.
I just want Python to return my dates column as how I originally inputted them. I do not want it to change the order of days, months or years or to add a time.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Change the type to the date time and use the same logic you used before

```
# Convert the 'Date_of_Birth' column to datetime
df['Date_of_Birth'] = pd.to_datetime(df_combined['Date_of_Birth'])

# Convert the 'Date_of_Birth' column back to string with the original format
df['Date_of_Birth'] = df_combined['Date_of_Birth'].dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
```

Comment: Hi Samed, I am reading in 5 separate worksheets within an Excel file. Therefore I don't want to convert the Date of Birth for each worksheet and then read each one separately into python. I want to use this code first and then change the date of Birth type once all worksheets have been amended.
# First, combine all the pages in each Workbook into one sheet

df_toAppend = pd.concat(pd.read_excel('C:/Sam/Predicting Outcomes .xlsx', sheet_name=None), ignore_index=True)